# What does plpy.notice(msg) do?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpy

Is it just a plain print to screen? if it is why not simply use simple console print command?

I've looked it up and there isn't much information about it. Even in the [official PostgreSQL guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpython-util.html) there isn't information about it other than the fact it exists.

Is it preferred to use `plpy` module because that way the information to be printed won't be logged in `PostgreSQL` log file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PL/Python `plpy.notice(msg)` method and its cousins, `plpy.debug(msg)`, `plpy.log(msg)`, `plpy.info(msg)`, `plpy.warning(msg)`, `plpy.error(msg)`, and `plpy.fatal(msg)` are used to generate messages using PostgreSQL's logging capabilities. The `error` and `fatal` variants also raise an exception which can be used to abort the current SQL transaction. `plpy.notice(msg)` is equivalent to the PL/PgSQL command `RAISE NOTICE msg`.

According to the PostgreSQL 9.4 documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpython-util.html, the destination of log messages at various levels can be controlled via database configuration variables. For example, you can specify that you only want messages of at least `WARNING` level to be dispatched to the client, but anything from `NOTICE` and above to be logged to the server log. This has been the case at least back to PostgreSQL 8.0.